# How to put variable to dat.js function

Tags: javascript

```
function GetStartTime(){


        var first=$('#<?php echo $this->SearchLimitDateCookiesName?>-year option:selected').val()+'-'+ $('#<?php echo $this->SearchLimitDateCookiesName?>-month option:selected').val()+'-'+$('#<?php echo $this->SearchLimitDateCookiesName?>-date option:selected').val()+' 00:00:00';
        var last=$('#<?php echo $this->SearchLimitDateCookiesName?>-year option:selected').val()+'-'+ $('#<?php echo $this->SearchLimitDateCookiesName?>-month option:selected').val()+'-'+$('#<?php echo $this->SearchLimitDateCookiesName?>-date option:selected').val()+' 59:59:59';

        var start_time = Date.parse(first).getTime()/1000;

        var last_time = Date.parse(last).getTime()/1000;

        var StartTime=start_time;
        var LastTime=last_time;

        $.cookie('<?php echo $this->SearchLimitDateCookiesName?>-start_time',StartTime,{expires:1});

        $.cookie('<?php echo $this->SearchLimitDateCookiesName?>-last_time',LastTime,{expires:1});

        }
```

why function Date.parse() is cannot send date time via 'first' variable.
if i'm put Date.parse('1970-02-23 00:00:00') that working

if i alert(first); it's show time correctly.

Comment: I bet if you also just put Date.parse(first) it will work, it is likely the getTime() that is screwing it up, likely because the date format isn't being converted to UTC properly

Answer (score 1):

You say that if you try `Date.parse('1970-02-23 00:00:00')` it works.  That is wrong.  The result of `Date.parse('1970-02-23 00:00:00')` is `NaN`.

You need to pass a string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date to `Date.parse()`. ([Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse))

For example, try passing `'23 Feb 1970 00:00:00'` or `'1970-02-23T00:00:00'` instead of `'1970-02-23 00:00:00'`.

Answer (score 0):

[Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) returns number of seconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC and it doesn't have method `getTime()`, I don't understand what are you trying to do< but maybe this will help:

```
var start_time = new Date(first).getTime()/1000;
```